# Matplotlib - Annotate plot with triangle shaped box

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to annotate the top left corner of my plot with a spiky, triangle shaped box with a letter inside, as seen in the picture below. I am only able to do a square box, but I want a triangle box.

```py
plt.annotate("A",
             xy = (0.05, 0.92),
             xycoords = "axes fraction",
             bbox = dict(boxstyle = "square", fc = "red"))
```

[image: illustration plot with a red triangle with the letter A inside it in the top left corner]

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/shapes_and_collections/artist_reference.html), you can draw any arbitrary shape you want.

This is not exactly what you wanted, but may get you by.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection


def label(xy, text):
    y = xy[1] - 0.15  # shift y-value for label so that it's below the artist
    plt.text(xy[0], y, text, ha="center", family='sans-serif', size=14)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

patches = []

# add a path patch
Path = mpath.Path
path_data = [
    (Path.MOVETO, [0.00, 0.00]),
    (Path.LINETO, [0.0, 1.0]),
    (Path.LINETO, [1.0, 1.0]),
    (Path.CLOSEPOLY, [0.0, 1.0])
    ]
codes, verts = zip(*path_data)
path = mpath.Path(verts, codes)
patch = mpatches.PathPatch(path)
patches.append(patch)

colors = np.linspace(0, 1, len(patches))
collection = PatchCollection(patches, alpha=0.3)
collection.set_array(np.array(colors))
ax.add_collection(collection)

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```